# Web API ActionFilterAttribute won't return a status when AJAX call triggers response

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, jquery-select2

I'm making a Select2 call from an MVC view using the following code:

```
ajax: {
    url: url,
    delay: 150,
    data: function (params) {
        return GMK_Select2QueryData(params, 30, additionalData);
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
        var resultsArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            resultsArr.push({
                id: data.items[i].id,
                text: data.items[i].text,
                description: data.items[i].description,
                data: data.items[i].data
            });
        }
        return {
            results: resultsArr,
            pagination: {
                more: data.more
            }
        };
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.status);
    },
    cache: false
}
```

I'm attempting to capture whether a session has timed out, then return the status code to the "error" function so that I can pop something up on the screen stating they need to log back in. Right now, I'm simply alerting to the screen for testing purposes.

I'm using a Web API ActionFilterAttribute, but when I create an error response, the jqXHR is always status = 0 no matter what I do.

```
public class SessionActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (ctx.Session == null || ctx.Session["user"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Response = filterContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout, "Session Timeout");
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work IMO. May be you can try throwing an exception instead of setting the response (may be a not so good approach, not sure) `throw new HttpResponseException(filterContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(StatusCode, ErrorMessage));` Or what happens if we don't call the `base.O nAction....`  in case session is null? Will that make any difference?

Comment: Do you have any other error handling like in your web.config or `global.asax` that would intercept status `408` and forward something else? Also check the browser's developer window and examine the http request properties to make sure its a server issue and not a client side issue, if you still see status 0 you know its a problem with how the server is sending the response.

Comment: I've checked it also and for me it works properly. Did you try make not ajax request?

Comment: Check your browser console to see whether there is any error message.If you are using web api the problem may be also because of CORS

Comment: @Developer Neither case worked.

Comment: @Igor Browser's developer tools show an ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE when calling the API endpoint. Not sure if that means it is malformed coming back or what.

Answer (score 0):

`SessionActionFilter` Action filter is perfect. No problem in filter

Please update Select2 call as follows:-

**Answer 1:-**

```
ajax: {
            url: url,
            delay: 150,
            data: function (params) {
                return GMK_Select2QueryData(params, 30, additionalData);
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                var resultsArr = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                    resultsArr.push({
                        id: data.items[i].id,
                        text: data.items[i].text,
                        description: data.items[i].description,
                        data: data.items[i].data
                    });
                }
                return {
                    results: resultsArr,
                    pagination: {
                        more: data.more
                    }
                };
            },
            params: {
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                }
            },
            cache: false
        }
```

Can get error in following ways

Using the transport option will cause select2 to break if you just want to handle response errors like in the example below.

```
transport: {
   return $.ajax().error(function() {
        alert("error fetching data"); 
   });
}
```

There is another, much simpler way to handle errors. That is by using the params option like the example below.

```
params: {
    error: function(response) {
        alert("error fetching data"); 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Please reference [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1854)

**Another Answer**

In Select2.js file add extension of "error"

serach for text "*$.extend(params*"

Then update extension by following code

```
$.extend(params, {
                url: url,
                dataType: options.dataType,
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (requestNumber < requestSequence) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // TODO - replace query.page with query so users have access to term, page, etc.
                    var results = options.results(data, query.page);
                    query.callback(results);
                },
                /* BEGIN added code */
                error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    if (requestNumber < requestSequence) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var r = null;
                    if (options.error) {
                        r = options.error(jqXHR, status, error);
                    }
                    query.callback(r || { results: [] });
                } /* END added code */
            });
```

And your updated ajax call

```
ajax: {
                url: url,
                delay: 150,
                data: function (params) {
                    return GMK_Select2QueryData(params, 30, additionalData);
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    var resultsArr = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                        resultsArr.push({
                            id: data.items[i].id,
                            text: data.items[i].text,
                            description: data.items[i].description,
                            data: data.items[i].data
                        });
                    }
                    return {
                        results: resultsArr,
                        pagination: {
                            more: data.more
                        }
                    };
                },
                 error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    alert(error + ": " + jqXHR.responseText + ": " + jqXHR.status);                    
                },
                cache: false
            }
```

Comment: I can't seem to hit error or success within the params object on Select2.

Comment: There is one another hack also, you might have notice in shared link. updated Answer. Both of them worked for me.

Comment: Had tried demo, Yes my first answer didn't work in your case but second worked!.. Please try second option.. Thanks

Comment: This extend doesn't exist in 4.0.3

Comment: Then "error: function (jqXHR, status, error)" will work without any hack in v4.0.3. Even this worked for me!! :)